# Inner class' instance not able to access Outer class' data member

Tags: java, inner-classes

The documentation says "An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance." This means with the instance of inner class, I can access the members of the outer class. But I am not able to do so.

```
public class TopLevel {

    private int length;

    private int breadth;

    public class NonstaticNested{
        private static final int var1 = 2;

        public int nonStaticNestedMethod(){
            System.out.println(var1);
            length = 2;
            breadth = 2;
            return length * breadth;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        TopLevel topLevel = new TopLevel();
        NonstaticNested nonStaticNested = topLevel.new NonstaticNested();

        // Trying to access the length variable on 'nonStaticNested' instance, but not able to do so.

    }

}
```

Comment: well... who knows without having a clue what you are doing or did. (no code provided)

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy just added the code. Please help.

Comment: Fix your formatting. It's hard to see what you're doing.

Comment: Can you show us the code you had instead of `// Trying to access the length variable on 'nonStaticNested' instance, but not able to do so. ` ?

Comment: `Trying to access the length variable on 'nonStaticNested' instance, but not able to do so.`, you might want to reread the basics, there is no `length` in `nonStaticNested`, there is only variable `length` for the Class `TopLevel`

Comment: Even after "adding the code" you still aren't showing the bit of code you're having problems with (the bit corresponding to "Trying to access the length variable") and you still aren't showing what result you are getting (compile-time error msg, run-time error msg, ...)

Comment: @RobinTopper    nonStaticNested.length = 2; // This line gives compilation error.

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy Yeah I completely understand, there isn't any length data member defined for the inner class, but the documentation says instance of inner class has direct access to fields of its enclosing instance.

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy maybe I am not able to decipher the meaning of 'its enclosing instance' correctly.

Comment: @parul which is `topLevel.length` here (in main), but not `nonStaticNested.length` here. The field `length` is defined in the class `TopLevel`, but you can acces the variable `length` within the inner class, as you already did in the constructor of it (That´s the meaning of access here)

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy But then in the example, it is not specifically the instance of inner class (nonStaticNested) that has direct access to field (length) of its enclosing instance (topLevel). Rather it is accessible in the main() method of the TopLevel class. 
I am clear with the idea that inner class in its body can directly access the data member of the outer class. But I am not talking about what is accessible inside the inner class itself, rather about what is accessible via the instance of the inner class outside the inner class. Is that not what the line is talking about too?

Comment: @parul access and ownership are two different things `.length` here tries to access the `length` variable, but the beforehand defined `nonStaticNested` in `nonStaticNested.length` implies, that `length` is defined within the class `NonStaticNested`, which it simply is not. Therefore you get the correct error message. just because `NonStaticNested` has access to variables defined within `TopLevel` it doesn´t make it the the owner of the variable.

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy Agreed, but maybe they could have used clearer words in the documentation, it was a bit confusing. Nonetheless, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the comments within the main are self speaking.

```
public class A {
    int a = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B(); 
        // Works as "a" is defined in "A"
        System.out.println(b.a);
        // Works as "b" is defined in "B"
        System.out.println(b.b);
        C c = new C();
        C.D d = c.new D();
        // Works as "c" is defined in "c"
        System.out.println(c.c);
        // Works as "d" is defined in "D"
        System.out.println(d.d);
        // Error here as there is no "c" defined within "D", it´s part of "C" and here´s your
        // logical mistake mixing it somewhat with what inheritance provides (just my guess).
        System.out.println(d.c);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int b = 1;
}

class C {
    int c = 1;
    class D {
        int d = 2;
        public D() {
            // Has access to "c" defined in C, but is not the owner.
            c = 2;
        }
    }
}
```